# merge two WebElements list

Tags: java, selenium

cannot print values from the merged lists as it is throwing me null!

```
List<WebElement> DateTime2 = driver.findElements(By.xpath(""));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).click();
List<WebElement> DateTime3 = driver.findElements(By.xpath(""));
List<WebElement> DateTime = new ArrayList<>(DateTime2);
DateTime.addAll(DateTime3);
Thread.sleep(2000);
System.out.println("This is for testing the list " + 
DateTime.get(2).getText());
System.out.println("This is for testing the list " + 
DateTime.get(30).getText());
```

i expect output to be printed date and time

Comment: whats the size of DateTime2 & DateTime3?

Comment: you should post the full error so I know _where_ the exception is being thrown from

Comment: @Sureshmanithe size for DateTime2 is 19 and DateTime3 is 19

Comment: @randypaq13 the exception is thrown at DateTime.get(2).getText());
j
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=71.0.3578.137 (86ee7228

Comment: findElements will return when at least 1 object is found.  Since you are getting "staleElement Exception" from Selenium, it's very possible that the list is still populating via client side script when you attempt to grab the elements.  You need to put this in a function, use a WebDriverWait and try/catch the stale element exception... if caught, re-run the function until stale element is no longer thrown (or after a certain number of tries...  it'll poll the DOM every 1/2 second.)

Comment: @pcalkins thank you ! is there any example i can follow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of some code I use (though I changed it a bit for this example.  This is usually a part of a class that extends another.)

```
int sanitycount= 0;
int ec_Timeout = 10; //seconds to wait for list... 
    public void RunAction(WebDriver driver, String in_xpath)
    {
                  try
      {
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, ec_Timeout);
        List<WebElement> found_elements = new ArrayList<>();
        found_elements = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(in_xpath)));

        if (!found_elements.isEmpty())
        {
        // store this array, return an array from function
        // or loop through array and add items to more global array..
        }

       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
       if (e.getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException"))
         {
         //need to do it again, not finished loading
         System.out.println("*****************Stale caught-redoing");
         sanitycount++;
         if (sanitycount<ec_Timeout * 2)
         {
         RunAction(driver, in_xpath);
         }
      System.out.println (e.toString());
      }
      else
      {
      System.out.println (e.toString());
      }
    }
  }
RunAction(your_driver, your_xpath); 
//set sanitycount back to zero if you run again...
```