# StaleElementReferenceError on iterations

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My application gets a list of IDs from the db. I iterate over these with a cursor & for every ID, I plug it into a URL with Selenium to get specific items on a page. This is doing a search on a keyword & getting the most relevant item to that search. There are around **1000** results from the db. At random iterations, 1 of the driver actions will throw up an `StaleElementReferenceError` with the full message of:

> stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document\n  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.75)

Looking at the [official docs](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp) I can see that the 2 common causes for this are:

- The element has been deleted entirely.
- The element is no longer attached to the DOM.

With the former being the most frequent cause.

**`index.js`**

```
const { MongoClient, ObjectID } = require('mongodb')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const { Builder, Capabilities, until, By } = require('selenium-webdriver')
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome')

require('dotenv').config()

async function init() {
    try {
        const chromeOpts = new chrome.Options()
        const ids = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'data', 'primary_ids.json'), 'utf8')
        const client = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.DB_URL || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {
            useNewUrlParser: true
        })
        const db = client.db(process.env.DB_NAME || 'test')
        const productCursor = db.collection('product').find(
            {
                accountId: ObjectID(process.env.ACCOUNT_ID),
                primaryId: {
                    $in: JSON.parse(ids)
                }
            },
            {
                _id: 1,
                primaryId: 1
            }
        )
        const resultsSelector = 'body #wrapper div.src-routes-search-style__container--2g429 div.src-routes-search-style__products--3rsz9'
        const mostRelevantSelector = `${resultsSelector}
            > div:nth-child(2)
            > div.src-routes-search-product-item-raw-style__product--3vH_O:nth-child(1)`
        const titleContainerSelector = `${mostRelevantSelector}
            > div.src-routes-search-product-item-raw-style__mainPart--1HEWx
            > div.src-routes-search-product-item-raw-style__containerText--3NefD
            > div.src-routes-search-product-item-raw-style__description--3swql
            > div.src-routes-search-product-item-raw-style__titleContainer--tazkH`
        const productImageSelector = `${mostRelevantSelector}
            > div.src-routes-search-product-item-raw-style__mainPart--1HEWx
            > div.src-routes-search-product-item-raw-style__containerImages--1PfdF
            > a.src-routes-search-product-item-raw-style__productImage--1Y42Y
            > img`
        const linkSelector = `${titleContainerSelector} > a`
        const primaryIdSelector = `${titleContainerSelector} > p`

        chromeOpts.setChromeBinaryPath('/usr/local/bin')

        const driver = await new Builder()
                .withCapabilities(Capabilities.chrome())
                .forBrowser('chrome')
                .build()

        let newProds = {}
        let product
        let i = 0

        while (await productCursor.hasNext()) {
            i += 1
            product = await productCursor.next()

            let searchablePrimaryId = product.primaryId
            let link
            let primaryId
            let pId
            let href
            let img
            let imgSrc

            if (product.primaryId.includes('#')) {
                searchablePrimaryId = product.primaryId.substr(0, product.primaryId.indexOf('#'))
            }
            if (searchablePrimaryId.includes('-')) {
                searchablePrimaryId = searchablePrimaryId.substr(0, searchablePrimaryId.indexOf('-'))
            }
            await driver.get(`https://icecat.biz/en/search?keyword=${encodeURIComponent(searchablePrimaryId.toLowerCase())}`)
            link = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css(linkSelector)), 10000) // wait 10 seconds
            img = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css(productImageSelector)), 10000)
            imgSrc = await img.getAttribute('src')
            primaryId = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css(primaryIdSelector)), 10000)
            pId = await primaryId.getText()
            href = await link.getAttribute('href')
            const iceCatId = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('-') + 1, href.length)
            const _iceCatId = iceCatId.substr(0, iceCatId.indexOf('.html'))
            const idFound = (searchablePrimaryId.toUpperCase() === pId.toUpperCase()) && !imgSrc.includes('logo-fullicecat')

            newProds[product._id.toString()] = {
                primaryId: product.primaryId,
                iceCatId:  idFound ? _iceCatId : 'N/A'
            }
        }
        const foundProducts = Object.values(newProds).filter(prod => prod.iceCatId !== 'N/A')
        console.log(`\nFound ${foundProducts.length}/${JSON.parse(ids).length}`)
        fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'data', 'new_products.json'), JSON.stringify(newProds, null, 4), 'utf8')

        driver.quit()
    } catch(err) {
        throw err
    }
}

init()
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
    })
```

To debug, I put a `try...catch` around each of the driver actions to see which specific action it is that is failing but that didn't work as it was never a consistent action that was failing. For example, sometimes if would have been one of the `elementLocated` lines or others it would have just been the `getAttribute` action.

If it is the latter in that scenario, that is why I am confused as to why this error is being thrown as surely selenium has found the element on the page *(i.e. `link`)* but is unable to do `getAttribute('src')` on the element? That's why I'm confused as to the error I'm getting. I imagine I must be doing something wrong with how I am setting up selenium to handle iterations. The iterations **never** get higher than **110**

Comment: this can happen when the dom is still being updated via client-side script between the time you find the element and the time you do something with it.  Catching the Stale Element exception might help.  If that specific exception is caught, re-run a find element/do something function. (WebDriverWait will throw timeout or stale element only.)  You can find an example of this (java) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57396173/merge-two-webelements-list/57400640#57400640

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the second cause is *The element is no longer attached to the DOM*. If a `WebElement` is located and the DOM is refreshed afterwards this element become stale even if the DOM hasn't change, the same locator will return new `WebElement`.

Normally, `driver.get()` will block until the page is fully loaded, however this site is running JavaScript to load the search results. You can test it by running `document.readyState` in the developer tools console, you will see `"complete"` results while the search results are still loading.

The page has a spinner before the results are located, hopefully it will be enough to wait for it to appear and became stale before scraping the page

```
await driver.get(`https://icecat.biz/en/search?keyword=${encodeURIComponent(searchablePrimaryId.toLowerCase())}`)

let spinner = driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(By.className('src-routes-search-style__loader---acti')))
driver.wait(until.stalenessOf(spinner))

link = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css(linkSelector)), 10000)
```

Comment: This was a great solution & led me to fixing my issue! The only things I changed were that `elementIsVisible` expects a WebElement instead of a selector so changed that to `elementLocated`. I also gave the `driver.wait()` a timeout of a minute. This didn't seem necessary at 1st but broke when I removed it. I now have:


`let spinner = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css(spinnerSelector)))`
`await driver.wait(until.stalenessOf(spinner), 60000) // 1 min`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have wait for Ajax request to finish. The website retrieves and refreshes dom once you go to end and also keeps calling index every few seconds so DOM probably keeps updating. You can probably hold AJAX requests, get your results, process and enable AJAX again.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try removing "await" from img Src = await img.getAttribute('src'). Since wait for img is already handled in its previous line.

Comment: It seems more like a comment instead of an answer.